# Javascript multiple OR statement not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code in Javascript (jQuery) and I need to acces inside a `IF` statement in case one condition became `TRUE`, but I always obtain `TRUE`, even the condition been `FALSE`, and I don't understand why. Here is the simple code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
    genere = vector[i].gender;
    pitch = synthProcess[i].pitch;
    mood = synthProcess[i].mood;
    speed = synthProcess[i].speed;
    identifier = synthProcess[i].ident;

    if (genere !== "auto" || pitch !== "0" || mood !== "0" || speed !== "0" || identifier !== "0"){
        console.log("EXECUTING COMMAND");
    }  
}
```

What I want is ONLY when `genere` is different from 'auto', `pitch` different from '0' etc, then, enter inside the `IF` but always is entering.
I tried with "0" (string) and 0 (int) options, but still getting the same result, in every iteration I get the `Log` inside the `IF`

Comment: statement in `OR` condition gets executed if one them is `true` and latter condition won't be checked.

Comment: Yes, of course, but in some cases I have: 'auto', '0', '0', '0', '0' and still entering inside... and don't know why

Comment: try to use single != then !==.

Comment: No @JamesThorpe , I only want enter inside IF, when just one of the statement become true, only one it's OK

Comment: @Sergi what if in this case `'auto', '0', '0', '0', '7a6sd6fasd6' ` should go in or not.

Comment: And if any of your variables are actually numbers rather than strings, you want `==` or change `"0"` to `0` as per @Parth's comment.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes it is strict type checking.

Comment: @Jai, in this case  'auto', '0', '0', '0', '7a6sd6fasd6' should go in

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, I tried to chane "0" to 0 but still the same result

Comment: Have you tried single != then !== ??

Comment: From the sounds of things you'll need to make the logic more complex than just one `if` statement if it should only go in if any one of them matches but not more than one - may need a count of how many are true and only execute the insides if the count === 1

Comment: @Sergi have you tried?

Comment: @Sergi that i have mentioned in 3rd Comment that change it !== then !=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a strict comparison, which checks the type of your variables as well. Like this:

```
var a = 'auto';
var b = 0;
var c = 0;

if (a !== 'auto' || b !== '0' || c !== '0') {
    // this will be called since (0 !== '0') = true
    console.log('called!');
}

if (a !== 'auto' || b != '0' || c != '0') {
    // this wont be called since (0 != '0') = false
    console.log('not called');
}
```

That is, if you compare a zero int with a 0 String using strict comparison, they will be considered different:

```
console.log(0 === '0') // prints false
console.log(0 !== '0') // prints true
```

If you compare then using a normal comparison, they will be considered the same:

```
console.log(0 == '0') // prints true
console.log(0 != '0') // prints false
```

Check out [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript) and [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yjwwuzn/1/).

Answer (score 1):

if values of pitch etc are int 
use-

```
var  genere = 'auto';
var pitch = 0;
var   mood = 0;
var speed = 0;
var  identifier = 0;
if (genere !== "auto" || pitch !== 0 || mood !== 0 || speed !== 0 || identifier !== 0){
        alert("EXECUTING COMMAND");
}
```

else, values of pitch etc are string [ex: '0']  then use

```
var  genere = 'auto';
var pitch = "0";
var   mood = "0";
var speed = "0";
var  identifier = "0";
if (genere !== "auto" || parseint(pitch) !== 0 || parseint(mood) !== 0 || parseint(speed) !== 0 || parseint(identifier) !== 0){
        alert("EXECUTING COMMAND");
}
```